# I can't make space between containers in css

Tags: html, css

i need help.
I have two containers A and B,  I want to make space between container A and container B, i tried to do this  with padding but it goes beneath container A or appirs the line below the containers
Thanks for answers) and sorry for my English

```
        body
        {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        .blok
        {
            
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #ccfff2;  

        }
        .row
        {
            float: left;
            width: 70%;
            background-color: #ff9999;          
        }
        .row-left
        {
          float: left; 
          background-color: #ffcc66;
          width: 30%;
        
        }
        .card
        {
            background-color: #ccffff;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px;   
        }

    </style>
</head>

<div class="blok">
    
    <div class="row">
        <h1>A</h1>
        <div class="card">  
           <h1>Hi</h1>
           <P>text</P>
        </div>
        <div class="card">  
           <h1>Hi</h1>
           <P>text</P>
        </div>
        <div class="card">  
           <h1>Hi</h1>
           <P>text</P>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-left">
        <h1>B</h1>
        <div class="card">
           <p>Image</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Space _between_ block containers (like a `div` or `section` etc.) is created by _margin_, not padding. Padding is space _within_ a container, between the container's border and its content.

Comment: O ma God yes, made a mistake, thank you)

Comment: :) you're welcome OksasaSmit. I'm voting to close your question as a "typo" ... or you may want to delete it yourself before someone decides to downvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your `row-left` class' style like this.

```
.row-left
{
  float: left; 
  margin-left:20px;
  background-color: #ffcc66;
  width: calc(30% - 20px);      
}
```

Comment: Only using margin will not be effective. Don't forget to use `width: calc(30% - 20px); `